# Error while trying to update Hasura in Digital Ocean

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, hasura

I am trying to update the hasura to latest image v1.2.2 by modifying the docker-compose.yaml of my droplet in Digital Ocean.

![Text] https://nimb.ws/1hM7f3

But when I try to restart using "docker-compose up -d"  I am getting the following error message.

![Test] https://nimb.ws/dMtc3P

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.Can some please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have too many spaces before `image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.2`. Try to align that row with the row below so that `image` and `depends_on` aligns vertically.